# GooglePlacesAutocomplete not working in react-native apk file for android

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api

I implemented Google Places API in my react native project and I'm trying to query places search with the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` but for android it only works while testing with expo and when I build a test apk and install on a real device no result is returned and GooglePlacesAutocomplete does not work. it is difficult for me to trace this error because in development environment everything works perfectly. please I really need help. below is how I query google places

```
 return (
<SafeAreaView style= {{backgroundColor: 'white', height: "100%"}}>
  <View >
  <Text style ={{ color: 'black', 
  fontWeight:'bold', 
  fontSize: 25, 
  padding: 10}}>Lets Move it!</Text>

  <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder='Move from?'
  styles={{
    container: {
      flex: 0,
      
    },
    textInput: {
      fontSize: 18,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 1,
      padding: 8,
      margin: 8,
      borderColor: '#a29e9e11'

    }
  }}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => {
    dispatch(setOrigin({
      location: details.geometry.location,
      description: data.description
    }))
    dispatch(setDestination(null))
  }}
  fetchDetails ={true}
  enablePoweredByContainer={false}
  
  query={{ key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY, language: 'en'}}

  nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' debounce={400}
   />

  
  </View>
  <View style ={{flex:1}}>
          <BottomView />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

Comment: Hope you have created API key for your project and enabled billing account for it, because when your free limit ends it will check it for billing account.

Comment: You can try to Alert the error so that we can help more

Comment: when testing with expo app everything works fine but when I build app and install on a real device it does not work

Comment: is there a way I can debug apk

Comment: Try to implement **renderRow** method and add alert in it. So might be you will get error in alert for release apk

Comment: Do you mean that App does not work on prod? Or is it still in debug mode?

Comment: app does not work on production but works in debug mode

Comment: but works on iOS development build

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below component I have implemented, its working on both mode debug and release, **(You can change some styles w.r.t. your application styles and need to handle images added)**

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', top : 37,width:40,height:40, paddingLeft : 15, zIndex:10}}
        onPress={()=>{
          navigation.goBack();
        }}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/images/backIcon.png')}
          style={{height: 35, width: 35}}
        />

      </TouchableOpacity>

        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Enter your search query"
          placeholderTextColor="#8189B0"
          query={{
            key: YOUR_API_KEY,
            language: 'en',
          }}
          textInputProps={{
            ref: textInput => {
              textInput && textInput.focus();
            },
          }}
          returnKeyType={'Search in Google'}
          listViewDisplayed={'auto'}
          fetchDetails={true}
          onPress={(data, details) => {
            console.log('Data=>', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('Details=>', JSON.stringify(details));
            navigation.goBack();
          }}
          renderRow={rowData => {
            const title = rowData.structured_formatting.main_text;
            const address = rowData.structured_formatting.secondary_text;
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  width: width - 80,
                  paddingBottom: 10,
                  paddingTop: 10,
                }}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/Location.png')}
                  style={{width: 35, height: 35}}
                  resizeMode={'contain'}
                />
                <View style={{height: 40, marginLeft: 8}}>
                  <Text
                    style={{color: '#0D1A59', fontSize: 16, paddingRight: 10}}
                    numberOfLines={1}>
                    {title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: 'rgba(13, 26, 89, 0.65)'}}>
                    {address}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }}
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GoogleReverseGeocoding"
          debounce={300}
          autoFocus={true}
          enablePoweredByContainer={false}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
          suppressDefaultStyles={true}
          styles={{
            container: {
              flex: 1,
            },
            textInput: {
              height: 40,
              color: '#2E3E5C',
              width: 300,
              fontSize: 14,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              borderRadius: 8,
              paddingHorizontal: 15,
              marginLeft : 30,
              backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF',
            },

            listView: {
              display: 'flex',
              top: 50,
              width: '93%',
              alignSelf: 'center',
              borderRadius: 8,
              height: height * 0.7,
            },
            row: {
              paddingLeft: 13,
              height: 60,
              flexDirection: 'row',
            },
            poweredContainer: {
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
              borderColor: '#c8c7cc',
              borderTopWidth: 0.5,
            },
          }}
        />
      {/* </View> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Comment: I think there's an issue with my Google API or something. because I just copied your code and it works while testing just like mine but when I build api with expo and install on my android devices it does not produce any result when I type

Comment: is it a must I restrict my api?

Comment: Which API you are talking about?

Comment: I mean my google api key

Comment: Nope, no need to restrict API key. But Make sure API key is enabled for Android platform and connected with billing account.